# C# proxy tester unbelievably slow even on its own thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, proxy

I wrote a simple proxy tester based on some code I found here.

the basic idea was, it loads a file which contains a list of proxies in the form of ipaddress:port, splits that into an array, and tests for connectivity.

I run this iteration in a second thread because it was unbearably slow. Its somewhat faster now but am hoping for some suggestions.

The bulk of the work is done here:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (this.lblCurrentProxy.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.lblCurrentProxy.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { this.lblCurrentProxy.Text = "Current proxy: " + line; ;});

    }
    else
    {
        this.lblCurrentProxy.Text = "Current proxy: " + line;
    }
    //lblCurrentProxy.Text = "Current proxy: " + line;
    String[] addressParts = line.Split(':');
    try
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(addressParts[0], Int32.Parse(addressParts[1]));
        wc.DownloadString("http://google.com/ncr");
        sw.WriteLine(line);
        //MessageBox.Show("working proxy");
    }
    catch
    {
        // do nothing, proxy was dead.
        continue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var fileName = "";
var workingProxies = new List<string>();
Parallel.ForEach(
    File.ReadLines(fileName),
    () => new List<string>(),
    (line, state, bucket) =>
    {
        String[] addressParts = line.Split(':');
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(addressParts[0], Int32.Parse(addressParts[1]));
            wc.DownloadString("http://google.com/ncr");

            bucket.Add(line);
        }
        catch { }
        return bucket;
    },
    subBucket =>
    {
        lock(workingProxies)
            workingProxies.AddRange(subBucket);
    }
);

//Now read from workingProxies
```

This gets the framework to handle the threading for you. Also note that all the UI interaction is removed. It doesn't make sense to have a 'current' proxy being tested when you may have *multiple* proxies being tested at once. Rather, this will check *all proxies*, and then simply tell you which proxies worked.

Of course, if you really wanted to, you could add some code after `bucket.Add(line)` to display it in the UI, but I'll leave that to you.

**Edit**
Here's a version without thread-local variables. This means that we need to lock every time we append to the list, rather than only locking when the threads complete.

```
var fileName = "";
var workingProxies = new List<string>();
Parallel.ForEach(
    File.ReadLines(fileName),
    line =>
    {
        String[] addressParts = line.Split(':');
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(addressParts[0], Int32.Parse(addressParts[1]));
            wc.DownloadString("http://google.com/ncr");

            lock (workingProxies)
                workingProxies.Add(line);
        }
        catch { }
    }
);
```

Comment: Parallel is something I am new to- can you explain a little on whats going on here? see it returning bucket, but to what? Very confused on this one..

Comment: @DanSmith `return bucket;` here is a bit misleading. Essentially, `Parallel.ForEach()` passes us a new `List<string>` for each *thread* (`() => new List<string>()`) defines this. This means that each thread is free to append to its `bucket` without any thread-safety issues. Now, if the thread-local type was a *integer*, we would need to return the new value, since an integer is not mutable. In the case of a `List` though, we simply want to append to the list, and then return the same list we're given

Comment: @DanSmith I've added an example without thread-local variables, as I believe that detracts from the goal here - should be a bit easier to understand

Comment: I will take another look at this. I am currently testing your version to see what it comes up with time-wise, but rather than writing the new list to a file I am just having it messagebox the Count of the list.

Comment: @DanSmith You definitely could. I haven't worked on desktop applications for a while, but I believe there's a progress bar control. In any case, you can dispatch the `progressBar.Invoke(() => /*update here*/);` after `wc.DownloadString()`. Shouldn't be any issues